# Embedding of separable $C^*$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a separable $C^*$-algebra. Can $A$ embedded into a separable, simple $C^*$-algebra?

Comment: Well for nuclear and exact $C^*$-algebras the statement is true because they embed in $\mathcal{O}_2$ which is separable and simple, so if someone feels like looking for a counter-example they should look elsewhere; personally I cannot even guess whether the statement is true or not in general!

Comment: @JustDroppedIn That's a valid point. We know that every separable $C^*$-algebra embedded in Calkin algebra, and Calking algebra is simple. But Calkin algebra is not separable, am I right?

Comment: I am not sure. The Calkin algebra is indeed simple. I also think it is not separable because $B(H)$ is not

Comment: @JustDroppedIn I think I've found the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In B. Blackadar, Weak expectations and nuclear C -algebras. Indiana Univ.
Math. J. 27 (1978), 1021-1026. Blackadar shows that every separable subalgebra of a simple $C^*$-algebra is contained is a simple separable $C^*$-subalgebra of $A$. In particular, every separable $C^*$-algebra can be embedded into a simple separable $C^*$-algebra (since it can be embedded into the Calking algebra).

Comment: This result of Blackadar is very nice, I was not aware of this. Thanks for an interesting question. May I ask, do you have a reference on why every separable $C^*$-algebra embeds in the Calkin algebra?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn It's easy: Let $\mathcal{Q}(H)$ be the Calkin algebra. Denote by $\pi : \mathcal{B}(H) \rightarrow \mathcal{Q}(H)$ the quotient map. If $A$ is a separable $C^*$-algebra there exists a faithful representation $\phi : A \rightarrow \mathcal{B}(H)$. Then $\phi' := \oplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \phi$ is an essential representation. Then $\pi \circ \phi'$ is a trivial embedding of $A$ into $\mathcal{Q}(H)$.

Comment: Oh yeah, of course. And the separability is required so that $H$ does not get crazy big but stays of countable dimension, so $Q(H)$ is indeed the Calkin algebra.

Comment: Also, i wonder who downvoted this answer. It is a fine answer in my opinion and I see no reason for this to be downvoted. Maybe the language can be improved, but that's why the edit button is there.

Comment: Also the question got downvoted. Weird!

Comment: @QuantumSpace I think someone in the functional analysis tag is being a little salty. Yesterday I got a downvote on a question with 4 upvotes

Comment: @QuantumSpace LOL, now someone is retracting upvotes on my posts. People be salty indeed